# Separating out observations that have been combined

Tags: r

I am struggling with a dataframe where someone has merged multiple identical observations into one. I want to separate out these observations so they appear as separate rows (i.e. one observation per row).

Here is a reprex:

```
x<- read.csv(text = "sample_id,organism,site\n101,E. coli, Blood\n102&103,S. aureus, Blood\n104, E. coli, Urine")
```

Somebody merged sample_id 102 and 103 as they had the same variable data. I want to separate out sample_id 102 and 103 but retain the variable information for each.